# Why won't my ASP.NET WebApi project on Linux listen to HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I know nothing about https, I am still learning, please forgive me if there are any rookie mistakes。

I am using DotNet 7, both Windows and Linux, the linux one is installed by `apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0`
I want to use https on my Asp.Net WebApi project.
On Windows, the project do listened https port

```
// Windows Outputs
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7166
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5163
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: E:\User5\Documents\VSProject\DotNetWebApi
```

But on Linux(I'm using Debian 11 and DotNet7), it only listened http port. No error message appear.

```
// Linux Outputs
lzhjk@VM-12-3-debian:~/DotNetWebApi$ dotnet run
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5163
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/Lzhjk/DotNetWebApi
```

I have already configured https url in Porperties/launchSettings.json,
and did not change anything that used to be in the Program.cs

```
// launchSettings.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31240",
      "sslPort": 44347
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5163",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7166;http://localhost:5163",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

11111

```
// Program.cs
global using DotNetWebApi.Models;
global using DotNetWebApi.Services;
global using DotNetWebApi.Dtos.Character;
global using AutoMapper;
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
global using DotNetWebApi.Data;


using DotNetWebApi.Services.CharacterService;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICharacterService, CharacterService>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);

var app = builder.Build();//

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();// is this a 
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I followed some simple instructions, typed some command, like clean and recreate the cert, but the problem is still the same:

`dotnet dev-certs https --clean`

`dotnet dev-certs https -t`

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)